# Does QList clear function call clears the memories of dynamically allocated objects that are stored in the QList?

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I have class called `AppointmentSchedule` which is of the following type:

```
namespace Ui {
class AppointmentSchedule;
}

class AppointmentSchedule : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AppointmentSchedule(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~AppointmentSchedule();
    Ui::AppointmentSchedule *ui;
};
```

The `ui` of this class consists of two objects of type `QLabel` and two objects of type `QDateTimeEdit`. In an external class, I need to have a `QList` of dynamically allocated objects of type `AppointmentSchedule`. I will append the dynamically allocated objects in the `QList` similar to the following way.

```
QList<AppointmentSchedule*> scheduleList;

foreach (QDate date, dates)
{
     AppointmentSchedule * newSchedule = new AppointmentSchedule(this);//Allocation of memory
     QDateTime sDateTime(date, QTime(8, 0, 0));
     newSchedule->ui->appointmentStartDateTimeEdit->setDateTime(sDateTime);
     QDateTime eDateTime(date, QTime(8, 15, 0));
     newSchedule->ui->appointmentEndDateTimeEdit->setDateTime(eDateTime);
     scheduleList.append(newSchedule);
}
```

If I call the `clear()` function of the `QList` like this:

```
scheduleList.clear();
```

Will it deallocate all the memory I have allocated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it deallocate all the memory I have allocated?

No, `clear()` only remove all items from the list. In your case this items are pointers on `AppointmentSchedule` objects.

As you set parent for `AppointmentSchedule` objects, this objects wiil be deleted when their parent will be destroyed. That's why there is no memory leak in your case.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it deallocate all the memory I have allocated?

No. You declared a list of *pointers* to `AppointmentSchedule` objects. When you call `clear`, those pointers will be deleted, but the memory they pointed to will remain untouched, so you'll get memory leak.

To deallocate the objects themselves, use either smart pointers (like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`) or delete them manually in any kind of `foreach` loop before calling `clear()`.

Edit:

In this case there will be no memory leak as Qt object hierarchy will take care of proper object destruction. See @Kirill's answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer soon. I have actually followed what you said about manually deleting them even before you wrote the answer. So, on that we agree. :)

Comment: But there is no memory leak in presented code. AppointmentSchedule objects has parent, that's why this objects will be deleted when parent object will be destroyed.

Comment: @the_naive Also pay attention at Kirill's answer. You set non-nullptr parents for your objects, so parent's destructor will delete them and you will not need to delete them manually. It's a feature of Qt's object hierarchy and is a common way to delete nested widgets.

Comment: @KirillChernikov Okay, I will not delete them manually. Thanks for both of your answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Since you use pointers:**
To avoid memory leaks, you need to delete every pointer for example with:

```
foreach(auto element, scheduleList)
{
    delete element;
}
```

Also if you use parent property in your AppointmentSchedule elements, they are automatically deleted upon parent deletion.

**Concerning the list itself:**
If you'd like to store large objects (not pointers) in the list, calling `.clear()` only removes accessible items, but it doesn't necessarily resize the container. If it did that every time you call it, it would be inefficient.

However you can call `.squeeze()` to free the unused memory.
It still does only remove the space allocated for pointers, not objects on the heap you allocated with `new` operator.

Comment: [`qDeleteAll`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms.html#qDeleteAll-1) is a convenience method for deleting all objects in a container

Comment: @king_nak +1 for that idiom